# Change value of input on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the value of inputs of a modal when you click submit to a panel. So, if a user write the input, the value that he write replace the content of the panel below. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x56EG/1/):

Main structure of the modal:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Task detail">

    <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="row-fluid" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
<form id="taskForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2"> 
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-1 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-10">
              <input id="inputName" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputURI" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-1 control-label">URI</label>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-8 col-md-10">
              <input id="inputURI" name="uri" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="URI" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPlanning" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-1 control-label">Planning</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-10">
              <input id="inputPlanning" name="planning" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Planning" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputOrder" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-1 control-label">Order</label>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-10">
              <input id="inputOrder" name="numOrder" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Order">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="chkActive" for="chkActive" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-1 control-label">Active</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-10">

              <div class="miniswitchmodal" style="float: left;">
              <input type="checkbox">
              <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
            </div> 

            </div>
          </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-success modalbtn">Save changes</button>
        <button id="btnClose" type="button" class="btn btn-default modalbtn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>  </form></div></div></div>
```

Main structure of the panel:

```
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div id="7" class="panel panel-off2">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">

      <div class="ptitle">Task 7</div>
     <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow"></span>
<div class="miniswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="7">
    <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
</div> 
  </div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript?

Comment: Learn about interacting with the dom via js.  Then learn about javascript events and forms.

Comment: Check the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x56EG/1/ I don't know how to get the value that write the user and set in the panel replacing the old one.